# C++11 closure shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

What is the syntax to create heap allocated closure manage by shared_ptr. I want to pass closures to functions and be able to pass nullptr. Seems like using a `shared_ptr< ::std::function<void()>` but I cannot figure the syntax to initialize that from a lambda expresion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be something like

```
auto lambda = []() { /* do something usefull */ };
auto p = std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>(lambda);
```

But actually you may no need `shared_ptr`, since [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) can be constructed from `nullptr`.

```
std::function<void()> fnc(nullptr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you want to create a `shared_ptr<X>` via `make_shared`, initializing the `X` object with some `Y` object. Then generally the code to do that is

```
auto ptr = make_shared<X>(someY);
```

In your case, `X` is the `std::function` type, and the `someY` is your lambda. Once you have that, it's pretty straight forward:

```
auto funPtr = std::make_shared<function<void()>>( [](){ std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; } );
(*funPtr)();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

```
std::function<void()> lambda = [](){};
auto heapPtr = std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>(lambda);
auto heapPtr2 = new std::function<void()>(lambda);
```

You might also find the following questions useful:

- [C++11 lambda implementation and memory model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202656/c11-lambda-implementation-and-memory-model)
- [In C++11 lambda syntax, heap-allocated closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670114/in-c11-lambda-syntax-heap-allocated-closures)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer putting shared_ptr inside the function object.

```
auto o = make_shared<MyData>();
return [o] ()
{
    ...
};
```

So, the data for the closure is on the heap and ref-counted while the handle can be copied and passed around. The data is cleaned up when the last handle is destroyed.